# Delete data from the table after renaming column Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Recently I've started with Laravel 5.8 and I'm trying to make the delete button which will delete row from the database. But before I create the button, I've Already Change the column id name in the table from id to id_book, the problem is Laravel still get the id-data, not id_book, and raise an error
like this

```
**Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'books.id'**
```

this is button's code:

```
<form action="/hapus/{{ $book->id_book }}" method="POST">
                @method('DELETE')
                @csrf
                <input type="submit" value="Hapus">
</form>
```

this is the Controller's Method:

```
public function hapus($id_book){
    $book = Books::find($id_book);
    $book->id;
    if($book->gambar = 1){
        Storage::delete($book->gambar);
        $book->delete();
        return redirect('/books');
    }
    else{
        $book->delete();
        return redirect('/books');
    }
```

the column in tables is:
id_book (previously is id),
name,
image,
category,
description

thank for help, this is my model after fixing this problem:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Books extends Model
{
protected $table = "books";
protected $primaryKey = "id_book";//solution

protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'images',
    'category',
    'description'
];
```

}

Comment: Please can you show the code you're using to delete the row?

Comment: Did you define the new primary key in your model?

Comment: @Jerodev, Alright I will try, what you sugested

Comment: is it possible to show the model please?

Comment: @Snoxik, sure bro

Comment: `I've Already Change the column id name in the table from id to id_book` - how did you do that?

Comment: @Don'tPanic, I am using migration, `php artisan make: migration rename_id_column`

Comment: And adding `$primaryKey` in your model did not solve it?  Maybe `composer dump-autoload`, clearing caches etc?

Comment: Don't know if it is necessary but the migration docs show a few things about primary keys 1) [`dropPrimary()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#dropping-indexes) key; 2) Add a new [`primary()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#creating-indexes) key.  Maybe you need to do those, as well as renaming the col?